# Use PHP to create thunderbird emails

Tags: php, mailto, thunderbird

I have a custom-written mySQL database of users (with PHP/HTML website interface) which I use for billing. I have a number of overdue invoices and would like to email these users to advise overdue state.

I can email users via PHP using PHPmailer etc, but would prefer to have an HTML link which I can click to compose a pre-filled thunderbird email. There are reasons for this including PHP mails being rejected as spam (the biggest server in NZ has seriously weird spam requirements which I cannot reliably get around). There are other reasons I want this done via TBird so please don't suggest *not* using TBird as a solution!

The mailto link is not reliably an option as I believe browsers have a GET query string  max-length which is too restrictive.

Any other options anyone knows of?

Comment: PHP is a server-side technology, and in no way whatsoever can dictate what mail client is available or used client-side. The only way you can invoke a mail client from PHP is to use a `mailto:` link in a page that PHP generated.

Comment: As @MarcB said, PHP has absolutely nothing to do with Thunderbird.  Whether your clients use Thunderbird is up to them and there's nothing you, or PHP, can do about it.

Comment: follow all the advise here to increase the change your mail not being marked as spam:http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.htmli assume you refer to yahoo\extras email host, have you filled-in this form http://help.yahoo.com/l/qe/snova/mail/postmaster/bulkv2.html?from_url=

Comment: Did you consider using phpmailer with an established email provider like gmail ?